# Why do I have to specialize it?

Tags: c++, templates

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cout;
using std::string;

template<int v>
struct Int2Type
{
    enum {value = v};
};

template<bool condition,class Left, class Right>
struct Result;


template<class Left, class Right>
struct Result<true,Left,Right>
{
    typedef Left value;
};

template<class Left, class Right>
struct Result<false,Left,Right>
{
    typedef Right value;
};


struct Ternary
{
    template<class Left, class Right>
    static Right check_(Int2Type<false>, Left left, Right right)
    {
        return right;
    }

    template<class Left, class Right>
    static Left check_(Int2Type<true>, Left left, Right right)
    {
        return left;
    }

    template<class Left, class Right>
    static auto check(bool condition, Left left, Right right)-> decltype(Result<condition,Left,Right>::value)
    {
        return check_(Int2Type<condition>,left,right);
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int a = 5;
    string s = "Hello";
    cout << Ternary::check(false,a,s);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting error:
"Error  1   error C2893: Failed to specialize function template ''unknown-type' Ternary::check(bool,Left,Right)'"

Why? 
**EDIT**

```
   template<class Left, class Right>
    static auto check(bool condition, Left left, Right right)-> 
        decltype(Result<(sizeof(int) == 1),Left,Right>::value)
    {
        return check_(Int2Type<condition>,left,right);
    }
```

added:

```
Result<(sizeof(int) == 1)
```

Comment: Types are compile-time constructs. If you don't know the parameters at compile-time, you cannot use the type.

Comment: @GMan I've tried with Result<sizeof(someexpression),Left,Right>::value but it doesn't work aswell and sizeof is compile time operator. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: What was `someexpression`? That needs to be known at compile-time too...

Comment: @GMan (sizeof(1) == 1 ? true : false)

Comment: `sizeof` may be a compile time operation, but `==` and `?:` aren't.

Comment: @Tyler ok so what's the solution to this? I mean how can I specify trailing return type in that case?

Comment: The result of the comparison is a boolean, no need for the conditional. `sizeof(1) == 1` should be a fine template parameter, maybe you should edit how you're testing that in. @Tyler: They are.

Comment: @GMan Have to go (my wife is calling me - it's 9 p.m and it's friday;) ) I'm going to check this topic tommorow. Hope to hear from you. Talk to you later.

Comment: Should be tagged C++0x, given your use of `auto`

Comment: @GMan Huh. I stand corrected. I knew that a compiler *could* process simple expressions on constants at compile-time, but I was unaware that doing so was a requirement of the language.

Answer (score 2):

`condition` here is a variable of your program.

A template parameter must be a constant expression (or a type), and therefore a variable is not suitable since the compiler cannot select the right specialization based on runtime information.

Answer (score 1):

```
static auto check(bool condition, Left left, Right right)-> decltype(Result<condition,Left,Right>::value)
```

What???

You can't use run-time variable `condition` to parametrize a template at compile time!?

Comment: Perhaps he meant `typeof (condition)`? err... but that won't work everywhere, will it?

Comment: No, first parameter of Result is `bool value`!

Answer (score 0):

Just write (after removing `check`):

```
cout << Ternary::check_(IntToType<false>,a,s);
```

Comment: yes but I want correct check_ to be selected according to first parameter.

Comment: @There: You *can't* have the return type of a function determined at runtime in C++.

Comment: @There is nothing... (hoo what a nick!) that's exactly what's gonna happen: In auto tResult = Ternary::check_(IntToType<false>, a, s); tResult will be of type 'Right', in your example std::string as you can easily verify by deltype(tResult) tOther = "surely a string". As has been stated from other posters, you cannot use a run-time variable (condition) as a class template id.